# how to generating a dropdown list in yii2

Tags: yii

I tried to make a dropdown list in yii2 using this link : [How to make a drop down list in yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569053/how-to-make-a-drop-down-list-in-yii2)

my code is :

```
<?php use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Product;
?>
<?= $listdata=ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(),'id','name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')-> dropDownList($listdata);  ?>
```

but I have a problem in line of using  **ArrayHelper**
the problem is:
 **PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
 Array to string conversion**.......! I tested the below code :

```
 $listData=ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->asArray()->all(),'id','name');
```

but it dos not solved and has the same error!

whats the problem? can somebody help me?

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($listdata)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to echo an array, change `<?=` to `<?php` in:

```
<?= $listdata=ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(),'id','name'); ?>
```

Comment: yes... you are right, I use <?php and it corected!!!  I am new in yii :) thanks very much my friends

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   <?php
     use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
     use app\models\Product;
    ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select ']) 
    ?>
```