# Dynamic Checkbox List in Yii2

Tags: arrays, dynamic, checkbox, yii2

So I'm trying to create a dynamic Checkbox List in Yii2.
I'm trying to adept the work done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092502/how-to-generating-a-dropdown-list-in-yii2) but without success. As described there i should use the ArrayHelper.

So first I am fetching the data (works)

```
$listData=ArrayHelper::map(EinsatzorteModel::find()->asArray()->all(),'id','location');
```

Output(shortend):

```
array(9) { 
   [1]=> string(18) "Region: Y" 
   [2]=> string(17) "Region: X"
}
```

Now I'm trying to add it to a checkbox list:

```
<?= $form   ->field($model, 'locations[]')
           ->checkboxList(
            [$listData]
           )->label('Regionen');
?>
```

Which errors to:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Obviously its an Array, but shouldn't it fit anyway? The checkbosList expects parameters to be given as

```
'A' => 'Item A'
```

which actually should fit the format from the ArrayHelper.

So where do I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply try `$listData` instead of `[$listData]`.