# yii2 listdata convert from yii1.x

Tags: yii, yii2, html.dropdownlistfor

How can i convert the following to yii2

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT count(*) FROM job_title');
$jobTitle  = JobTitle ::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependency)->findAll($array);
$jobTitleList = CHtml::listData($jobTitle, 'job_title_id','desc');
return $jobTitleList;
```

I have the following code which does not work.

```
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;

$items = array();
foreach (Jobsprocess::find()->where($array)->all() as $value) {
    $items[$value->process_id] = $value->jobsprocess;
}
return $items;
```

Comment: read this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569053/how-to-make-a-drop-down-list-in-yii2

Comment: are you asking about the alternative for CHtml::listData in yii2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the following code in Yii 2 format.

> Yii 1:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT count(*) FROM job_title');
$jobTitle  = JobTitle ::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependency)->findAll($array);
$jobTitleList = CHtml::listData($jobTitle, 'job_title_id','desc');
return $jobTitleList;
```

> Yii 2:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\JobTitle;

$jobTitleList = ArrayHelper::map(JobTitle::find()->where($array)->all(), 'job_title_id','desc');
return $jobTitleList;
```

But I don't know what are you doing with `Jobsprocess` model in the `Yii 2` code. Because, In the `Yii 1` format you haven't used that model.

Comment: He is asking only about equivalent for Yii 2. How it's different from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Replacement for `CHtml::listData` in Yii 2 is `ArrayHelper::map()` Example:

```
$jobTitleList = ArrayHelper::map($jobTitle, 'job_title_id', 'desc');
```

Read more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map%28%29-detail).