# Yii2-user, dektrium-yii2-user, Yii2 Populate a dropdown in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I am pretty sure that there is a better way to populate the array, needed for the dropdown:

```
<?php 

$items2 = [Yii::$app->user->identity->id => Yii::$app->user->identity->username ]; ?>
<!--...some html -->

<?= $form->field($model, 'idUser')->dropDownList($items2,['Item' => ''])?>
```

already try:

```
$item2 = ArrayHelper::map(Yii::$app->user->identity::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

reason, I want to display 'name' but submit 'value'='id'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a drop down list in yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569053/how-to-make-a-drop-down-list-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idUser')->
        dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Yii::$app->user->identity->find()->all(),
      'id', 'username'), ['prompt'=>'Select...'])?>
```

Comment: $items2 = ArrayHelper::map(Yii::$app->user->identity, 'id', 'name');
die($items2);
returns "Array", not the values that i need.  $items2 = [ '0' => 'crlshn' ]

Comment: I have update the answer and checked for dektrium user now return the dropdown with the username and assign the id